# Converting Java Boolean array to C++ bool array

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to convert a boolean array being passed to C++ from Java into just a bool array. However, regardless of what the boolean value is, it is always evaluated to true because the value is a number greater than 0. My latest attempt code is:

```
jint capsLen = env->GetArrayLength(capabilities);
if (capsLen <= 0)
{
  print error;
  return;
}

bool capsArray[capsLen];
jboolean *getbool = env->GetBooleanArrayElements(capabilities, NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < capsLen; i++)
  capsArray[i] = (bool)getbool[i]
```

I have also tried:

```
jboolean getbool[1];
bool capsArray[capsLen];

for (int i = 0; i < capsLen; i++)
{
    env->GetBooleanArrayRegion(capabilities, i, 1, getbool);
    capsArray[i] = getbool;
}
```

Both bits of code gives the `getbool` variable an integer value greater than 1.

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong, and cannot seem to find any example code online that works (that is if I can find anything at all). How am I supposed to rip boolean values from a jbooleanArray passed from Java into a bool array in C++?

Also, in case someone suggests it, I cannot use an integer array instead of a boolean array because the Java code HAS to have the information as booleans.

**EDIT:** @sigpwned For the first code block, an example of the returned values (using `printf("%d", getbool[i])`):

208, 160, 155, 65, 248, 106, 154, 65, 248, 106, 154, 65

It should be noted that these numbers are not always consistent.

**EDIT:** The provided boolean values are:

F, T, T, F, F, F, T, F, T, F, T, T

**EDIT:** Full function code

```
JNIEXPORT bool JNICALL Java_com_NativeClient_Login(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring userJ, jstring passJ, jstring serJ, jboolean useJ, jstring resJ, jbooleanArray capabilities)
{
  LOGI("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
  if (cst_ == NULL) {
    LOGE("cst is not initialized");
    return false;
  }

  std::string user = env->GetStringUTFChars(userJ, NULL);
  std::string pass = env->GetStringUTFChars(passJ, NULL);
  std::string ser = env->GetStringUTFChars(serJ, NULL);
  std::string res = env->GetStringUTFChars(resJ, NULL);
  jint capsLen = env->GetArrayLength(capabilities);
  if (capsLen <= 0) {
    LOGE("Provided capabilities array is empty or negative or errored");
    return false;
  }

  bool capsArray[capsLen];
  jboolean *getbool = env->GetBooleanArrayElements(capabilities, NULL);
  LOGE("sizeof(getbool): %d", sizeof(getbool));  // Returns: 4
  for (int i = 0; i < capsLen; i++) {
    capsArray[i] = (getbool[i] == JNI_TRUE);
    LOGE("capsArray[%d]: %d", i, capsArray[i]); // All zero
    capsArray[i] = !(getbool[i] == JNI_FALSE);
    LOGE("capsArray[%d]: %d", i, capsArray[i]);  // All one
  }

  if (!cst_->SetCapabilitiesArray(capsArray, capsLen)) {
    LOGE("Error is setting capabilities array, most likely it is a length mismatch");
    return false;
  }

  cst_->SetUserInfo(user, pass, ser, useJ, res);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What values are actually read into `getbool` by the C++ program? In other words, can you `printf` all the values of `getbool` after it's read?

Comment: i was indeed thinking use int. but i was also not seeing why you can't  just do the conversion from int to bool on the fly as needed right after you get the info. assuming the int values made sense/were parsable.

Comment: @LanternMike: I would love to convert passed integers to bools in C++, but the Java code can only give me booleans.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the even/odd values and the true/false values? If so, the last bit may be the boolean.

Comment: @isaach1000: There appears to not be any correlation between the T/F entries and the values seen in the print log.

Comment: You should hex dump what your `jboolean` pointer points to, to understand how the data is laid out.  And you should **not** cast that pointer to C `bool`, but should use it as is.  A Java boolean can be any size - byte, halfword, word - it's up to the implementation.  Presumably `jboolean` is defined to match the size that the implementation uses.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour. If I printf the results of getbool I get ones and zeroes, as expected. I can copy them to a bool array safely by comparing them to JNI_TRUE instead of casting. I think you need to show a bit more of your code.

Comment: @Arthur: The sizeof(getbool) is 4. I am printing getbool[i] to try and see if the typical bool values would appear.

Comment: @user2758929: Which block of code are you testing with? I have tried taking getbool and comparing it to both JNI_TRUE and JNI_FALSE, and neither case is reached. The only additional bit of code that is relevant is the parameter `jbooleanArray capabilities` being passed into the function.

Comment: @AeroBuffalo my native code is as follows: http://pastebin.com/DrYGYhNz compiled using MinGW/GCC on Windows 7. Could you update your post with the complete source code of your native method?

Comment: @user2758929: See updated post with entire code. I looked at your code, and the best that I can tell is that there is no difference. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't spot any obvious mistake in your code right now. Except that you shouldn't try to instantiate a dynamically sized array on the stack (capsArray) - use the new and delete operators for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was not with the C++ side of code, but my lack of knowledge of Java and stubbornness to ask the Java people for help.

It turns out that I was building and passing my function a `Boolean caps[]` instead of a `boolean caps[]`.